# ASP.NET MVC How to create a custom role provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication, asp.net-authorization

Being relatively new to ASP MVC, I'm unsure which would better suit my needs. I have built an intranet site using Windows authentication and I'm able to secure controllers and actions using the Active Directory roles, e.g.

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
[Authorize(Users="DOMAIN\User")]
public ActionResult SecureArea()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "This is a secure area.";
    return View();
}
```

I need to define my own security roles independent of the AD roles. The desired functionality is that authenticated users are granted access to specific actions according to one or more roles associated with their profile in my application database e.g: "Manager", "User", "Guest", "Analyst", "Developer" etc.

**How do I create a custom role provider and/or custom authorization attribute(s)?**

Comment: I think asking for the best/cleanest way is going to get a lot of different answers. A good approach is top-down. That is - authorizing at the controller level and then restricting at the method/action level depending on needs. You can also implement an area Base Controller and then each controller in that area implements the base. The area base controller can redirect to an appropriate page if the level of authorization is not met.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

My solution was to create a custom role provider. Here are the steps I took, in case anyone else needs help later:

**Create your custom user and role classes**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
namespace Security.Models.Security
{
    public class AppRole : IdentityRole
    {
    }
}
```

**and**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
namespace Security.Models.Security
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }
}
```

**Set up your database context**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Security.Models.Security;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Security.Models.DAL
{
    public class UserContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
        public UserContext() : base("UserContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<UserContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<UserContext>());
        }
    }
}
```

**Create your role provider and implement the following methods**

```
using Security.Models.DAL;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace Security.Models.Security
{
    public class AppRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        public override string[] GetAllRoles()
        {
            using (var userContext = new UserContext())
            {
                return userContext.Roles.Select(r => r.Name).ToArray();
            }
        }

        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            using (var userContext = new UserContext())
            {
                var user = userContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
                var userRoles = userContext.Roles.Select(r => r.Name);

                if (user == null)
                    return new string[] { };
                return user.Roles == null ? new string[] { } :
                    userRoles.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            using (var userContext = new UserContext())
            {
                var user = userContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
                var userRoles = userContext.Roles.Select(r => r.Name);

                if (user == null)
                    return false;
                return user.Roles != null &&
                    userRoles.Any(r => r == roleName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit your web.config to set up the database connection and role provider reference**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="UserContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UserContext.mdf;Initial Catalog=UserContext;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**and**

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <authentication mode="Windows" />        
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AppRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AppRoleProvider" type="Security.Models.Security.AppRoleProvider" connectionStringName = "UserContext"/>
      </providers>
      ...
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
```

**In package manager console, enable migrations**

```
enable-migrations
```

**In the newly created Configurations.cs set up the user/role stores and managers and configure the user manager validator to accept '\' characters**

```
namespace Security.Migrations
{
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
    using Security.Models.Security;
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Security.Models.DAL.UserContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            ContextKey = "Security.Models.DAL.UserContext";
        }

        protected override void Seed(Security.Models.DAL.UserContext db)
        {
            // Set up the role store and the role manager
            var roleStore = new RoleStore<AppRole>(db);
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<AppRole>(roleStore);

            // Set up the user store and the user mananger
            var userStore = new UserStore<AppUser>(db);
            var userManager = new UserManager<AppUser>(userStore);

            // Ensure that the user manager is able to accept special characters for userNames (e.g. '\' in the 'DOMAIN\username')            
            userManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<AppUser>(userManager) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };

            // Seed the database with the administrator role if it does not already exist
            if (!db.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Administrator"))
            {
                var role = new AppRole { Name = "Administrator" };
                roleManager.Create(role);
            }

            // Seed the database with the administrator user if it does not already exist
            if (!db.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == @"DOMAIN\admin"))
            {
                var user = new AppUser { UserName = @"DOMAIN\admin" };
                userManager.Create(user);
                // Assign the administrator role to this user
                userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Administrator");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In package manager console, ensure the database is created and seeded**

```
update-database
```

**Create a custom authorization attribute that will redirect to an access denied page on failure**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Security.Models.Security
{
    public class AccessDeniedAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

            if(filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/AccessDenied");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**You're done! You can now create an access denied page (in this case ~/Home/AccessDenied) and apply the attribute to any action, e.g.**

```
using Security.Models.Security;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Security.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
         ...    

        [AccessDeniedAuthorizationAttribute(Roles = "Administrator")]
        public ActionResult SecureArea()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult AccessDenied()
        {
            return View();
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This post helped me a lot.
But

var userRoles = userContext.Roles.Select(r => r.Name);

Does not get the current users roles, it gets all roles.

I was wondering why everyone had access lol.

Comment: Is this an answer to the original post, or just a general comment?